# Trigger click programatically on a single element of a list in Angular/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I am writing a test where I want to click on say the second item in a list and check that something has changed.

I have a bullet list element:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

I have tried the following (*element* is the angular element containing the entire list):

```
var li = element.find('li');

li.triggerHandler('click'); //Clicks all elements
li[1].triggerHandler('click'); //Error: li[1].triggerHandler is not a function
```

None of these works. The first attempt clicks all items and the second throws an error.

Any ideas how to only trigger click on the second item?

Comment: Why aren't you simply binding a click handler to the second element with ng-click?

Comment: I am. This is test code where I want to trigger a click on a single element to check that the code in _ng-click_ works as expected.

Comment: <li ng-click="function()">Item 2</li>

Comment: Ok I see, I missed that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`triggerHandler` only works on jQuery (or the builtin jqLite) elements. `element.find` returns a jQuery element (`li`) but `li[1]` [is a DOM node](https://api.jquery.com/get/), not a jQuery wrapped element.
You could use `element.find('li:eq(1)')` (if you use jQuery) or `element.find('li').eq(1)` (with the builtin jqLite) instead.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. However, I found out that the correct syntax (in my Jasmine/Karma test) is element.find('li').eq(1). Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Right, that's because `element.find` is "Limited to lookups by tag name" in jqLite. Updated the answer with clarifications for this.